# how can i fetch/get images from cloudinary folder to create a dynamic list in my react app

Tags: reactjs, axios, cloudinary

I want to get the images I uploaded to my Cloudinary folder so that I can use them to create a dynamic list. I also want to give the image details dynamically that match the index of the images in the Cloudinary folder. My get call is returning a 401 error. please point me out as to what part of my function is wrong.

I used the useEffect hook and Axios to fetch the data from Cloudinary and then I used the response to match the index of the images and my image's details. However, the response was an error message that ranged from 401 -404 depending on the Cloudinary API URL format I tried to use

//getting the cakes in the folder

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const displayCakeImages = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dxiybrrpf/resources/image/folder/Cakes`
          { auth: { apikey: "918126763482363", password: "" } }
        );
        const cakeDetails = [
          { id: 1, name: "first cake", price: 20 },
          { id: 2, name: "second cake", price: 10 },
          { id: 3, name: "third cake", price: 40 },
          { id: 4, name: "fourth cake", price: 20 },
          { id: 5, name: "firth cake", price: 40 },
        ];

        const fetchedImages = response.data.resources;
        const giveImageDetails = fetchedImages.map((image) => {
          const imageDetail = cakeDetails.find(
            (imageDetail) => imageDetail.id === image.public_id
          );
          return {
            ...image,
            name: imageDetail ? imageDetail.name : "",
            price: imageDetail ? imageDetail.price : "",
          };
        });
        setDisplayCakes(giveImageDetails);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching cake images:", error);
        if (error.response) {
          console.error("Cloudinary error response:", error.response.data);
        }
      }
    };
    displayCakeImages();
  }, []);
```

Comment: The code after the call to `axios.get` isn't really relevant to this question. 401 means you haven't supplied correct authentication credentials. 403 means you've successfully authenticated but you don't have permission to perform the requested action. 404 means there's nothing at the URL you've requested. If you can share the shapes of the `axios` requests which resulted in each of those statuses and any additional information which may have been in the responses then it'll make the question easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

The URL you're trying to request doesn't match a valid API endpoint on Cloudinary. In place of where you have `folder` in the URL, it should be the `:type` (e.g. `upload`) or [another valid Cloudinary `type`](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#delivery_types) - in the current state, you should receive a 400 Bad Request response because `folder` is not a valid `type`.

Assuming you fixed and used a valid `type`, if you include another component in the path as you have done with the value `Cakes`, this means you're asking Cloudinary to return details of the asset with `public_id` => `Cakes` - and if you don't have such an asset then you should receive a 404 Not Found in response. Effectively, you would be calling the [Get details of a single resource by public ID](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_details_of_a_single_resource_by_public_id) method as the URL would match the one for this endpoint.

More generally, all API endpoints that are part of the Cloudinary [Admin API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api) should not be called from the client side - in fact, if you try and make a cross-origin request then that will be blocked by the Browser because CORS is intentionally not configured for those endpoints. The [Admin API uses Basic Authentication](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#overview) and that relies on your Cloudinary product environment `API Key` and `API Secret`. The API Secret should not be used/exposed anywhere on the client side and should be used only on the server side.

If your goal is to query your Cloudinary product environment and retrieve all assets stored in a particular folder, e.g. `Cakes` in your example, then you should consider one of the following solutions:

1. From the client side, send a request to your server and make the Admin API call from your server to Cloudinary to retrieve the results, then send that response back from your server to your React app. Depending on the language you're using on your server, I'd recommend using one of [Cloudinary's backend SDKs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/backend_sdks) which make it easier to send requests to Cloudinary by providing you with relevant methods you can just pass parameters to rather than sending HTTP requests directly. The Admin API method you would want to use is called [Get resources](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources). To get a list of resources from the `Cakes` folder you should pass the parameter `prefix` with the value of `Cakes/` and also the relevant `type` (e.g. `upload`).
2. Alternatively, another option for getting a list of resources is using the [Resource Lists](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/advanced_url_delivery_options#client_side_asset_lists) feature via the client side. When you're uploading the assets in the folder, you could assign them a tag with the same name as the folder (e.g. `Cakes`) and then you could retrieve a list of those assets (up to 1,000), by making a request that asks Cloudinary to return all assets with the given tag. If all your assets have the `Cakes` tag which are in that same folder, then Resource Lists would allow you to retrieve them by making a request from the client side directly without needing to go through your server first.